# WSL2 Xdebug PhpStorm Time-out connecting to client

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, wsl-2

I know it has been asked many times, but I tried 20 other solutions and spent all day and nothing seems to work.

I have WSL2 running PHP 7.4 + Xdebug 2.9.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 and using PhpStorm 2021.2 on a new Windows 11.

php.ini

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.discover_client_host=no
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=172.19.144.1
```

Logs

```
[29220] Log opened at 2022-01-10 18:54:56
[29220] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.19.144.1:9003.
[29220] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
[29220] Log closed at 2022-01-10 18:54:56
```

`$ cat /etc/resolv.conf // nameserver 172.19.144.1`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple network issue, it was Public network instead of private, so the port 9003 was being blocked, even though there was a firewall rule in place (including Public...).

[image]

Comment: Hi @shadoweb, Im having the same issue like you. Could you please let me know the descriptive answer. really stuck here. I also have WSL2 running PHP 7.4 + Xdebug 2.9.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 and using PhpStorm in windows 10

Comment: Go to Firewall & Network protection, there is a link "Allow an app through firewall" then make sure Private and Public are checked on your PhpStorm.
I've edited my answer. I hope this was your issue!