# WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04, and PhpStorm - Xdebug 2.9.2 not able to connect

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, xdebug, wsl-2

I have been trying to setup the mentioned to get Xdebug to work. I have search the internet for answers, I have found none that work. After going through the motions of setting it all up, when I run the debugger against a break in my code I get "Connection was not established".

[image: Error]

```
-dxdebug.remote_enable=1
-dxdebug.remote_port=9000
-dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
```

[image: Interpreter]

[image: Debug settings]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add `xdebug.remote_autostart`? The `-d` part is what I really don't understand; use the config file.

Comment: *"remote_host=127.0.0.1"* I'm not sure that this is how you work with Xdebug on WSL2... The IP address that Windows gets to a host is dynamic and `127.0.0.1` _should_ not work. I say check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70657814/wsl2-xdebug-phpstorm-time-out-connecting-to-client to start with. Then check other similarly tagged questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdebug+wsl-2

Comment: See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#configure-xdebug-wsl. Your remote host address is incorrect.